# How do I get all entries 5 minutes after a certain condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, time, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to solve the following problem using SQL:

I have a table (example shown below) with action items per user, the timestamp when the action happened and a unique identifier for each entry.
I want to find out what actions each user takes in the 5 minutes after a specific action occurs. For example, I want to see for all users with the action item "sit" what happens in the 5 minutes after that, so to see all entries starting with the "sit" action item.
I hope someone can help!!
Thank you!

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko7bn.jpg)

I started using ROW_NUMBER and then partition by users and order by time, but after that I dont know how to continue.

Comment: Pls share your table/data in plain text instead of images (it would be better if you can provide DDLs to generate the table and data). Pls also add the expected output, and what you have done until now.

Comment: See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear, however, in my understanding, it is easier to use a JOIN

```
create table log(UserName varchar(20),ActionTime datetime,ActionItem varchar(10),ActionId varchar(26));
insert into log values
 ('Anna'    ,cast('2022-07-30 13:17:22' as datetime),'walk'   ,'uid_1')
,('Peter'   ,cast('2022-07-30 15:39:46' as datetime),'drive'  ,'uid_2')
,('Sarah'   ,cast('2022-07-30 09:07:53' as datetime),'stand'  ,'uid_3')  
,('Kurt'    ,cast('2022-07-30 00:56:14' as datetime),'sit'    ,'uid_4')  
,('Deborah' ,cast('2022-07-30 15:26:02' as datetime),'lie'    ,'uid_5')  
,('Michelle',cast('2022-07-30 15:26:03' as datetime),'scratch','uid_6')  
,('Sven'    ,cast('2022-07-30 15:26:04' as datetime),'run'    ,'uid_7')  
,('Sarah'   ,cast('2022-07-30 15:28:06' as datetime),'swim'   ,'uid_8')  
,('Peter'   ,cast('2022-07-30 13:17:22' as datetime),'look'   ,'uid_9')  
;
select a.ActionId,a.UserName,a.ActionItem,a.ActionTime
      ,b.ActionTime,b.UserName,b.ActionItem,b.ActionId
from log a left join log b 
  on  b.ActionId<>a.ActionId
  and b.ActionTime>=a.ActionTime
  and datediff(mi,a.ActionTime,b.ActionTime)<5
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this problem can not be solved with a single query. But you can use a series of queries.

In answer to your question I will use MySQL dialect of SQL. I believe it doesn't matter.

**On first step** let's assume that we are only interested in the last action "**sit**". In this case we can do such query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_actions WHERE ACTION_ITEM = "sit" ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1;
```

So the result is

```
+------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| USER | TIMESTAMP           | ACTION_ITEM | UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER |
+------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| Kurt | 2022-07-30 00:56:14 | sit         |                 4 |
+------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Then save timestamp value in variable:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP INTO @reason_ts FROM user_actions WHERE ACTION_ITEM = "sit" ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1;
```

And now we need to get further actions **in next 5 minutes** (actually I took 12 hours because 5 minutes is not enough for your example). Let's do this:

```
SELECT csq.* FROM user_actions AS csq WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN @reason_ts AND ADDTIME(@reason_ts, '12:00:00');
```

The result is:

```
+-------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| USER  | TIMESTAMP           | ACTION_ITEM | UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER |
+-------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| Sarah | 2022-07-30 09:07:53 | stand       |                 3 |
| Kurt  | 2022-07-30 00:56:14 | sit         |                 4 |
+-------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

If you need **all** further action modify query:

```
SELECT csq.* FROM user_actions AS csq WHERE TIMESTAMP >= @reason_ts;
```

If you need **not only last** action "**sit**" it will be more difficult. I think you need to write some kind of script or sql function. But still it is doable.